# how to change particular array element background color in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

below is my HTML code, I want to change the NameList array color while clicking on that particular array index, example if I click on `NameList[1]`
only that element background color change to green, again if I click `NameList[2]` then `NameList[1]` background change to white and `nameList[2]` change to green , how to fix this in angular 6.

```html
 
 <div>
 <ul *ngFor="let name of NameList">
      <tr>
         <td class=""  (click)="nameDetail(name)">{{name}}</td>
        </tr>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally use NgClass Here's the reference link https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ngClass` as suggested by `Ritik` or you can use `ngStyle`

```
[ngClass]="{'changeColor': name.active}"

[ngStyle]="{'background': name.active ? 'green':'white'}"
```

here is a link of working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2bp7x8)

Comment: I want to change just an normal array element color ,   example                      
  NameList=[User1,User2,User3,user4]; without using array object

Comment: did you check the demo? I think as per your question, this is fulfilling your requirements but still you think this is not fulfilling your requirements then I am unable to understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: you are inserting an object inside the array, it works only for key value elements(json object) , but i need normal elements like array=[1,2,3]. anyhow it is also useful for json objects thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional based CSS using ngClass

```
<div [className]="condition ? 'example-class' : 'other-class'"></div>


<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>
<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">..
</some-element>
<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>
<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

Let me know if you still not able to change background color.

Answer (score 0):

```
//html code

<td (click)="select(name)"
 [class.highlight]="isSelected(name)"
>{{name}}</td>

//Ts code
selectedName = '';

select(name){
    this.selectedName = name;
}

isSelected(name){
    return this.selectedName === name;
}
//css code
.highlight{
  background: #42A948; /* green */
}
```

Comment: @Ajay can you please explain about `[class.highlight]`. because something new for me, and I am curious to know more about this. thanks
and also please provide an example link if it is possible for you.

Comment: @FarhatZaman please go through this link https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding